# Nullish coalescing assignment (??=) causing issue on TV browser. How to elegantly resolve this

Tags: angular, babeljs, television, esbuild, browser-support

I am running an Angular (v17) app for our product which is also used on TV's by our customer.
When migrating from our React app to a brand new Angular app, we got these Nullish coalescing assignment (??=) errors on the TV.
I resolved it by using a `.browserslistrc` file and locking in version 12 of Safari, because that build was the only build that didn't add operators that TV browsers don't accept.
This fixed worked, but I was going 4 versions back from latest (at the time 16) but now Safari moved to version 17 so my browserlist version of Safari is now 13 which includes those operators again.
And the App breaks on the TV.

That is the introduction.
My question is, besides locking browserlist to Safari 12, is there another better way of having Angular build without the operators that break. If I remember, it is not the only operator (??=) that breaks but I don't know for sure.

I tried altering my ts-config with different targets but that didn't work. Using the browserlist Safari 12 approach was the only thing that for babel/esbuild (not sure which) to build in a way that is acceptable for most TV Browsers.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If your browser doesn't know how to deal with this operator, the only way is, not to use it in the final app. You may not even use it yourself but it may be part of recent angular runtime. The TS config only applies to your code being compiled, not the runtime. So actually the only way is transpiling during the creation of the web app package. And you have to transpile to a target that doesn't support the null coalescing assignment to have it removed. So yeah, locking to a quite old browser is the only way.

Comment: Do you have `.babelrc`?

Comment: If you know for sure it's just this operator and your build chain is using babel, you could try https://babeljs.io/docs/babel-plugin-transform-logical-assignment-operators while still transpiling for newer browsers. But I expect other new JS features to fail as well ...

Comment: But I wonder, that using safari13 as target will keep the `?==` because according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_assignment) this supported only as of safari14 ...